# What's the difference between carob powder, flour, and kibbled carob?

Tags: flavor, ingredient-selection, food-processing, carob

The whole carob pod, the pulp and the seeds are all edible, but which parts are used for the different core products? Does carob powder contain the entire pod, or just the seeds? Is kibbled carob the same as powdered, just coarser? Is the pulp used for anything? (And what is carob syrup!?)

Answer (score 2):

Almost 90% of the carob is pulp, and the rest is the seeds. From the seeds, you get Locust Bean Gum, or Carob Gum.

The pulp can be used either as:

Carob Powder/Carob Flour, which has sweet and chocolate-like taste.

Carob Kibble, which is basically much coarser pieces of the pulp.

Carob Syrup, if you extract the sugar from the pods, you get the syrup.

Comment: +1... so close to complete! What about carob chips? Are they re-condensed powder/flour or polished/further processed kibble?